# How to change css background-color in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am getting html code from `iframe` and want to set background-color to this class: `class="body"`

My HTML source looks like this:

```
<iframe id="sc_ext_XT29EK" class="sc_ext" width="100%" height="1300px" frameborder="0" src="some-url" scrolling="no">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<body class="body">

    ....

</html>
```

I have tried with this jQuery code but not worked for me.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $('iframe').load(function() {
        $("iframe").contents().find(".body").css('background-color', 'red'); 
    });  
</script>
```

First I have tried to check if color is working or not. If works I want to set `background-color` to `none`.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You cant modify the iframe content. If that is possible then i can get google search with my logo.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible. You aren't allowed to access the DOM of a page on a different origin.

If you have the cooperation of skycheck, you could [post a message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to the page in the frame and it could listen for that message and set the class based on it.